# Difference between calling [super dealloc] and calling the superclass' method implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

What is the difference between calling `[super dealloc]` and getting the IMP from the super class and calling that?

```
Method deallocMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([self superclass], @selector(dealloc));
IMP superImp = method_getImplementation(deallocMethod);
((void (*)(id, SEL))superImp)(self, _cmd);
```

I am getting two different behaviors depending on what I use. I am seeing this different behavior in a dynamic subclass of UIViewController.

**Edit**:

To elaborate. I am not using ARC.

Also the difference in behavior is hard to describe but I will try my best. It seems some cleanup that UIViewController does is in dealloc is not being done. If I call just [super dealloc] I get a message being sent to a deallocated instance of the view controller. This occurs when it is growing a hash of view controllers for views (something internal that I don't completely understand) in a static function of UIViewController (+[UIViewController setViewController:forView:]). My guess is that the view controllers are not being removed from the hash in the case where I only call `[super dealloc]`.

Comment: If you're using ARC then all bets are off.

Comment: What are the differences in behaviour? It's easier to explain symptoms when we know what they are.

Comment: I just added more of a description of the behavior difference. I am not 100% clear on exactly what is different. I was hoping an answer here might give me a hint but I did my best to describe it.

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing anything like this in shipping code.... and there shouldn't be a reason for it.

Comment: I am trying to avoid doing this and that is why I am trying to figure out what the difference would be. Hopefully once I know why it is behaving differently I can figure out how to fix it using the normal `[super dealloc]`

Answer (score 1):

You dont call [super dealloc] in ARC. Otherwise both are same.

Answer (score 0):

I got here after literally hours of googling and looking through book pages, trying to call the super's version of a method (but not knowing the method's name at compile time).

This was it, it all cleared it out for me. I've been getting it right about 90% except for the function pointer syntax.

The `((void (*)(id, SEL))` part was all that I was lacking.

I was doing the equivalent of `superImp (self, _cmd)` and kept wondering how come that it works (debugger was showing me that the superclass version of the function was executing) but when the green line of the debugger returned to the original line of the call I was getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = well...whatever)`

Curious thing...I remember reading about function pointers many-many-many years ago, and when I came across this topic, drewag's syntax made sense...however I encountered many other topics describing the issue along the lines of "grab the IMP and simply use it to make the call". No one on the other topics mentioned anything about stating the nature of the parameters and the return type.

Thank you, drewag.